# Last edit of google sheet from api

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the edit history of a particular cell in google sheet with python

```py
# Say I have the cell
cell = worksheet.cell(1,1)
cell_data = cell.value
last_edit_time = cell.last_updated # what can I do to get the last time the cell was edited?

# Print the cell data and last edit time
print('Cell data:', cell_data)
print('Last edit time:', last_edit_time)
```

Comment: Hey just a question do you have GCP access?